# Parallelization of image processing on very large image set in MATLAB without Parallel Processing Toolkit

Tags: image, matlab, parallel-processing

I have apprxoimately 2,500,000 images to process on a single computer. I currently run sequentially an input image for a single output to my function (it takes ~5 seconds to compute). This obviously takes too much time. What other methods can I employ to speed up the process? I thought of starting multiple instances of MATLAB and running each on a subset of the data, but I'm not sure if I truly achieve parallelism with this method. What are better methods of increasing the overall speed?

Comment: Try it. Unless your PC runs out of memory, splitting it to multiple matlab instances should be faster.

Comment: Search for some of my answers on SO for `GNU Parallel`... are you on Windows though?

Comment: If you have 4 cores, i.e. 8 Threads, it is probably only efficient to start 4 MATLAB instances, as MATLAB internally does some multi-thread processing when handling matrices.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I am on Windows and unfortunately I must use MATLAB. Is it possible to use GNU parallel with MATLAB?

Comment: Many functions in MATLAB are already multithreaded, so unless your code isn't taking advantage of that (I.e. isn't sufficiently vectorised) you will not see speed up by running multiple MATLABs (same logic applies to using Parallel Computing Toolbox)

Comment: @Olivier: I would say GNU Parallel or similar is the second step. First of all try to split it and check if the performance increases.

Comment: @Edric: I don't get your argument. With code which is not using multi core you have conditions which allow a nearly linear speedup when running it in parallel.

Comment: Don't get bitten by multiple threads fighting over access to a single I/O pathway and making throughput slower ...

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: @Daniel I agree - but many (most?) image processing algorithms already are multithreaded (especially those from Image Processing Toolbox). Multi-process parallelism is only beneficial when multi-threaded parallelism can't be used, and if you can arrange your code to take advantage of multi-threading, that will almost always be more efficient than multi-process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no-one seems to be helping out, I thought I would have a little attempt and see if I can get you started with some parallelisation. I do not use Windows or Matlab, so it may need some correcting... so, if anyone knows better... feel free to contribute.

You can install GNU Parallel under Cygwin in Windows - there are plenty of tutorials and blogs describing the process if you Google them.

First, I'm guessing/hoping that the following command will process one such image from the command line, so have a little experiment and see if that will work before you move to the next step

```
matlab.exe -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('mfile.m image.jpg');exit;"
```

Then, to run in parallel, you will need to generate a list of all 2,500,000 JPEGs, so that will look something like this

```
DIR /B /S | FINDSTR /I "*JPG$"
```

and you will need to feed that into GNU Parallel, something like this

```
DIR /B /S | FINDSTR /I "*JPG$" | parallel matlab.exe -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('mfile.m {}');exit;"
```

Obviously test this out on a dummy directory with a copy of a few of your files so that nothing gets broken or overwritten.

As @Daniel suggests, there is overhead to starting Matlab, so it would probably be better to change your code to process all images supplied as arguments, then maybe you could pass 2-8 images to each invocation of Matlab, something like this for 4 images per Matlab job:

```
DIR /B /S | FINDSTR /I "*JPG$" | parallel -N 4 matlab.exe -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('mfile.m {1} {2} {3} {4}');exit;"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I use for long running matlab processes, but starting restarting matlab for each image is a bad idea. This solution might be slower than the sequential version.

I would recommend to start Matlab with jobs of 15min to 1h each, so passing multiple images at once.

Comment: @Daniel Excellent! Thank you so much for the feedback. Maybe the OP can change his code, if even necessary, to process multiple images for a single invocation of Matlab - I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks for the responses, this gives me a good direction.